# How to insert Video by Web into UITABBAR IOS 5.0

Tags: ios5

I need to insert many videos taken from a website and add it in UITabBar,
I created my BarItems that are six, but now I have to implement the video in them,
how can I do? what library can I use?

Thanks for the support!

Alexander